# find the location of Finding Pattern (FP) in an image using python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I'm working on a program to aligning images containing a scanned document (align with the original document) by applying affine transformation based on 3 points of FP (Finding Pattern)(exactly like FP in QR Code). I'm trying to find the coordinate of the FP pattern in an image. In the picture, there are 3 FPs located at each near the corner of the image. This FP has a pattern like FP in QR Code with a ratio of 1:1:3:1:1. The image of the document may be rotated or of a different size, so it is possible that the pattern ratio is not exactly 1:1:3:1:1. So I have to use a tolerance value for that.

I've tried with a template matching approach, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133437/template-matching-with-multiple-objects-opencv-python), but I didn't get any results. (the form of the document that I mean is also explained there)

I've tried using `np.where`, but that can't be done for pattern search in the form of ratios. Are there any suggestions or solutions for this?